# Setting attributes of elements of type chr in recursive lists

Tags: r

I am very confused why the following code **works to set an attribute**:

```
#list of character
temp = list()
temp[[1]] = "test"
str(temp)
attr(temp[[1]], "testing") = "try"
attributes(temp[[1]])
```

which returns

```
$testing
[1] "try"
```

but when I try to set attributes of elements in a named list, say using

```
#list of character, where list element is named
temp = list()
temp[["2ndtemp"]][[1]] = "test"
str(temp)
attr(temp[["2ndtemp"]][[1]],"testing") = "try"
attributes(temp[["2ndtemp"]][[1]])
```

this returns `NULL`.

I then found that if you declare a recursive list:

```
#list of a list
temp = list()
temp[["2ndtemp"]] = list()
temp[["2ndtemp"]][[1]] = "test"
str(temp)
attr(temp[["2ndtemp"]][[1]],"testing") = "try"
attributes(temp[["2ndtemp"]][[1]])
```

this **works**.

Exploring further:

```
#character vector
temp = "test"
str(temp)
attr(temp,"testing") = "try"
attributes(temp)
```

**works** as well, but if I have a vector containing a character:

```
temp=vector()
temp[[1]] = "test"
str(temp)
attr(temp[[1]],"testing") = "try"
attributes(temp[[1]])
```

this returns `NULL`.

Can someone please explain to me why the attr() function is working differently in these cases?

EDIT: I am exceedingly confused by the last pair of examples, since if I set:

```
temp = "test"
temp2=vector()
temp2[[1]] = "test"
```

and then query:

```
identical(temp,temp2[[1]])
```

I get `TRUE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your examples do different things.

```
temp = list()
temp[["2ndtemp"]][[1]] = "test"
```

This creates a character vector, `[[<-`  on a null object does not create a list

see

```
x <- NULL
x[[1]] <- 'x'
 x
[1] "x"
```

In your example with `vector`, you are using the default value for `mode` when calling `vector()`, which is `vector(mode = "logical", length = 0)`

So when you assign `'test'`, you are just coercing from `logical` to `character`. It is still an atomic vector, not a `list`

As it is a character vector, and atomic, you can't give different elements different attributes, and

```
attr(x[[1]], 'try') <- 'testing'
```

doesn't actually assign anything (perhaps it should give a warning, but it doesn't).

You will be well served by reading the help page for `vector`

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, are you saying that elements of vectors cannot be given attributes?

Comment: @Alex elements of atomic vectors (character, integer, logical, numeric, complex, raw) cannot be given individual level attributes, Elements of `list` vectors can.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question. Now I just find it weird and painful that I need to declare a recursive list (example 3) in order to give these elements attributes.

Comment: You can do `temp[["2ndtemp"]] <- list('test')` to initialize the nested list (then `[[<-` will add to the list.